# Фракталы. Что, где и как?

Tags: python, математика, фракталы, javascript, алгоритм

Заинтересовался [фракталами](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB) в самом общем смысле. То есть мне визуальная часть интересна в меньшей степени, больше интересно самоподобие.
Есть прекрасная упрощенная модель - как [клеточный автомат](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82), в частности игра ["Жизнь"](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%96%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BD%D1%8C_(%D0%B8%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0)). Такую систему можно нетрудно смоделировать (что уже давно сделано всеми возможными способами), и ее можно использовать для разных практических вещей в качестве модели.
Вот стало интересно, где и как применяют фракталы, кроме рендеров тумана и прочих визуальных вещей? Какие-нибудь интересные алгоритмы, может игры? 
Также интересно, какие есть библиотеки для фракталов на `python` и на `js` (тут не уверен, что есть)?

Comment: Есть алгоритмы фрактального сжатия

Comment: Например вот [Основы фрактального сжатия изображений](http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/algorithm/126653/).

Comment: Spectre, можете оформить как ответ, чтобы вопрос не висел в неотвеченных